# grails.app.context being ignored deploying to Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails

I have an Apache server proxying all traffic from `mainhost.com/subdirectory` to `someec2instance/subdirectory`. When I start Apache and hit `someec2instance.com`, I get the ROOT war page. That works fine. If I deploy my app as ROOT.war, everything works fine form `someec2instance.com`.

However, when I access `mainhost.com/subdirectory`, all the asset urls and `link_to` urls are wrong and point to `mainhost.com` instead of `mainhost.com/subdirectory`.

I've set `grails.app.context` and confirmed via `application.properties` that the correct `grails.env` is being set.

Why isn't `grails.app.context` being respected when I deploy as `ROOT.war`? I would expect the site to be accessible on `someec2instance.com/context`, but it's like it ignore `grails.app.context` entirely.

Comment: Yes it is ignoring grails.app.context. You need to rename ROOT.war to ContextName.war.

Comment: I think the apache config needs to be changed to support that, but ultimately that's the better way to go. I don't have access to apache right now so I'll try when I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is doesn't work is that those settings are for running locally, not when deployed as a WAR file. When you use the tomcat or jetty plugin in `run-app` we configure the container to make it look like it's running an "exploded" war (similar to when a WAR gets unpacked to the file system by various servers). Since the container is running in embedded mode, it's easy to configure it programmatically as needed.

But when you deploy a WAR file there's nowhere near as much configurability. In `run-app` the build logic of Grails starts the server, configures it, and deploys the app, but a WAR file deployed to a "real" server is managed by the server and not the other way around.

Comment: Makes sense. If I deploy at contextINeed.war, it looks like things work fine. I just need to configure apache to proxy correctly.